# Android Studio Canary 14 - Unsupported plugin option Problem

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I started working on a sample Jetpack compose project. While compiling I get the following error.

My BuildGradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 29

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  buildFeatures {
    compose true
  }


  // To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into

  // bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    useIR = true
  }

  composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.0'
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-alpha06"
  }
}

dependencies {
  def composeVersion = "1.0.0-beta05"

  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
  implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
  implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
  implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion"
  implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion"
  implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha08"
  implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion"
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

My buildgradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Unsupported plugin option:
> androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to latest version (`1.0.0-beta06` when writing the answer) and make sure kotlinCompilerVersion is same as the Kotlin plugin version of your android studio. You have mentioned ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32' in your project level build.gradle file, So in your app level build.gradle file replace

```
composeOptions {
 kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.0'
 kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-alpha06"   
}
```

with

```
composeOptions {
 kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
 kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta06"
}
```